# zsh: Autocomplete filenames if no other completion available

Tags: command-line, zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

Many commands expect a filename as one of their arguments. When hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> in bash it autocompletes the filenames of the current directory by default. This is not the case in zsh (oh-my-zsh). How can I enable this behaviour?

When hitting the <kbd>tab</kbd> key after `mvn -am -pl` I'd expect to be able to autocomplete a directory name in the current directory.

Comment: It works for me out of the box, even in a clean Zsh install, no config required. Are you sure you have any files in the dir where you're trying to complete? Or perhaps you have `zstyle` that ignores them? Can you update your question with a reproducible test case?